# PHP array element need to output the same on my sample

Tags: php

I have this code below that I want to make the output  like this json:

```
 [{avatarUrl: '',messages: 
       [{time: ,text: ''},
        {time: ,text: ''},
        {time: ,text: ''}]}
 ,{own: true,messages:
      [{time: ,text: ''},
       {time: ,text: ''},
       {time: ,text: ''}]}
 ,{avatarUrl: '',messages: 
       [{time: ,text: ''},
        {time: ,text: ''},
        {time: ,text: ''},
        {time: ,text: ''},
        {time: ,text: ''}]}
 ,{own: true,messages:
      [{time: ,text: ''},
       {time: ,text: ''},
       {time: ,text: ''}]}]
```

Because on my current codes the output is this, I also added the exact result of my mysql fetch array :

```
[{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:31:52","text":"hellooo"}]},
{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:31:54","text":"hi"}]},
{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:31:56","text":"yes"}]},
{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:31:58","text":"ano yun"}]},
{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:32:20","text":"jjj"}],"own":true},{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:32:22","text":"kasdkaskds"}],"own":true},{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:33:47","text":"yes"}],"own":true},{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:33:50","text":" WHatzz"}],"own":true},{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:33:51","text":"up"}],"own":true},{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:33:52","text":"jejes"}],"own":true},{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:33:53","text":"s"}],"own":true},{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 15:33:53","text":"ssSs"}],"own":true},{"avatarUrl":"assets\/img\/avatars\/avatar_02_tn.png","messages":[{"time":"2019-02-22 ...



empfrom  empto   empmsg      xdatetime            xuser   
-------  ------  ----------  -------------------  --------
119      144     hellooo     2019-02-22 15:31:52  119     
119      144     hi          2019-02-22 15:31:54  119     
119      144     yes         2019-02-22 15:31:56  119     
119      144     ano yun     2019-02-22 15:31:58  119     
144      119     jjj         2019-02-22 15:32:20  144     
144      119     kasdkaskds  2019-02-22 15:32:22  144     
144      119     yes         2019-02-22 15:33:47  144     
144      119      WHatzz     2019-02-22 15:33:50  144     
144      119     up          2019-02-22 15:33:51  144     
144      119     jejes       2019-02-22 15:33:52  144     
144      119     s           2019-02-22 15:33:53  144     
144      119     ssSs        2019-02-22 15:33:53  144     
144      119     s           2019-02-22 15:33:53  144     
144      119     s           2019-02-22 15:33:53  144     
144      119     s           2019-02-22 15:33:53  144     
144      119     s           2019-02-22 15:33:54  144     
144      119     s           2019-02-22 15:33:54  144     
144      119     sa          2019-02-22 15:33:54  144     
144      119     a           2019-02-22 15:33:54  144     
144      119     as          2019-02-22 15:33:54  144     
144      119     d           2019-02-22 15:33:55  144     
144      119     as          2019-02-22 15:33:56  144     
144      119     jsjsd       2019-02-22 15:34:04  144     
144      119     asd         2019-02-22 15:34:04  144     
144      119     as          2019-02-22 15:34:04  144     
144      119     a           2019-02-22 15:34:05  144     
144      119     ajsjsjksd   2019-02-22 15:34:06  144     
144      119     sdasd       2019-02-22 15:34:07  144     
144      119     wew         2019-02-22 15:34:08  144
```

And this is my code. I already add some trappings to copycat the exact format but I cant still replicate. Any idea or do I neeed to add some condition.

```
       $json_response_list = array();
        $json_response = array();
        $json_msgx = array();
        $own = 0;
        $from = 0;
        $mydata = "";
        $ctr = 1;
        $cx = 1;
        $sql = "SELECT empfrom,empto,empmsg,xdatetime,xuser FROM chatbox WHERE xdelete = 0  AND (empto = '".$_POST['userto']."' OR empfrom = '".$_POST['userto']."') AND (empto = '".$_SESSION['crmuserid']."' OR empfrom = '".$_SESSION['crmuserid']."' )  ORDER BY xdatetime ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn1,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($sql));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if($row['xuser']==$_SESSION['crmuserid']){
                if($own==0){
                    $json_response['own'] = true;
                    $own = 1;
                    $from = 0;
                    $cx = 1;
                }
            }else{
                if($from==0){
                    $json_response['avatarUrl'] = "assets/img/avatars/avatar_02_tn.png";
                    $from = 1;
                    $own = 0;
                    $cx = 1;
                }
            }

            $json_response['messages'] = array();
            $json_msgx['time'] = $row['xdatetime'];
            $json_msgx['text'] = $row['empmsg'];
            array_push($json_response['messages'],$json_msgx);  
            if($ctr!=1 && $cx==1){
                array_push($json_response_list,$json_response);     
            }

            $ctr++;
            $cx++;
        }

        $jsonData = json_encode($json_response_list); //JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
        echo $jsonData;
```

Comment: I've got no clue what you're asking, not even the topic seems to be clear. Please read [ask]

Comment: Sorry for the confuse, all I want is to have ab exact output  an array like this  {avatarUrl: '',messages: 
       [{time: ,text: ''},
        {time: ,text: ''},
        {time: ,text: ''}]}
 ,{own: true,messages:
      [{time: ,text: ''},
       {time: ,text: ''},
       {time: ,text: ''}]}]...

Comment: So you want to output invalid json?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I dont know if this an invalid json but if it is. Indeed I want to output  this kind of format .

Comment: `{time: ,text: ''}` is obviously invalid

Comment: ...and the next question will be: Why is my AJAX request not working?

Comment: Can you please share your code (output) $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)

Comment: Hello @PraveenKumar the resul of mysql fetcht  is on my "Because on my current codes the output is this " message .

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone it will work if I will get the exact format of json output.

Comment: @kevinHaroldlabajo Can you please share your $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) array. So I will help you. I need your database result array

Comment: Hello @PraveenKumar I edited my question and add the result .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the json format that I want to achieve to be output is not possible, specially inside a loop because it will automatically replicate the non existing element of array. Below is the sample code I made to make it work.

```
        $json_response_list = array();
        $json_response = array();
        $json_msgx = array();

        $own = 0;
        $from = 0;
        $mydata = "";
        $ctr = 1;
        $cx = 1;
        $sql = "SELECT empfrom,empto,empmsg,xdatetime,xuser FROM chatbox WHERE xdelete = 0  AND (empto = '".$_POST['userto']."' OR empfrom = '".$_POST['userto']."') AND (empto = '".$_SESSION['crmuserid']."' OR empfrom = '".$_SESSION['crmuserid']."' )  ORDER BY xdatetime ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn1,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($sql));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            if($row['xuser']==$_SESSION['crmuserid']){

                if($own==0){
                    if($cx!=1 && $ctr!="1"){
                        array_push($json_response_list,$json_response);     
                    }
                    $json_response['avatarUrl'] = "";
                    $json_response['own'] = "1";
                    $own = 1;
                    $from = 0;
                    $cx = 1;
                    $json_response['messages'] = array();
                }
            }else{

                if($from==0){
                    if($cx!=1 && $ctr!="1"){
                        array_push($json_response_list,$json_response);     
                    }
                    $json_response['avatarUrl'] = "assets/img/avatars/avatar_02_tn.png";    
                    $json_response['own'] = "";
                    $from = 1;
                    $own = 0;
                    $cx = 1;
                    $json_response['messages'] = array();
                }
            }


            $json_msgx['time'] = $row['xuser'];
            $json_msgx['text'] = $row['xuser'];
            array_push($json_response['messages'],$json_msgx);  

            $ctr++;
            $cx++;
        }

        $jsonData = json_encode($json_response_list); //JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
        echo $jsonData;
```